# No recipient addresses found in header - Sendmail

Tags: perl, sendmail

I am using the below code.

I have printed my `$to` variable and it is fine. I am still getting error

> No recipient addresses found in header

```
my $sendmail = "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t";
my $reply_to = "Reply-to: swa.udda\@lkl.com";;
my $subject  = $lSubjectLine;
my $content  = $lMessage;
my $to       = "To: ".$lEmailAdd;
my $file     = $l_finalFile;
my $from     = "From: test.a\@lkl.com";

open( SENDMAIL, "|$sendmail" ) or die "Cannot open $sendmail: $!";
print SENDMAIL <<EOM;
$reply_to
$subject
$from
$to
$content
EOM
close(SENDMAIL);
```

Comment: What is this, email code from 1997?

Comment: `$lSubjectLine` isn't set.

Comment: As hinted by @melpomene, it is highly recommended you use a library at least to build the e-mail (and ideally send it). It will avoid a lot of misery for you.

Comment: IMHO in some lightweight perl scripts it makes sense to use sendmail (or sendmail look alike) to send simple email messages.

Comment: Instead of `print`ing to your `SENDMAIL` filehandle, try `printing` to `STDOUT`. That way you'll see exactly what data you are sending to `sendmail`. If you see an empty line, then remember that will end your headers and start the email content.

Answer (score 1):

The script you provided (as you provided it) generates empty line (end of headers mark) after `Reply-To:` header.

Modify you script to inspect message you pass to sendmail.

```
my $sendmail = "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i";

my $MSG=<<EOM;
...
EOM

print $MSG; # print message to STDOUT for inspection

open( SENDMAIL, "|$sendmail" ) or die "Cannot open $sendmail: $!";
print SENDMAIL $MSG;
close(SENDMAIL);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old submission, but just in case there's still interest, instead of blindly putting your string together, only add the bits that are actually set.

```
my $sendmail = "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t";
my $reply_to = "Reply-to: swa.udda\@lkl.com";;
my $subject  = $lSubjectLine;
my $content  = $lMessage;
my $to       = "To: ".$lEmailAdd;
my $file     = $l_finalFile;
my $from     = "From: test.a\@lkl.com";

open( SENDMAIL, "|$sendmail" ) or die "Cannot open $sendmail: $!";
print SENDMAIL join "\n", $reply_to, $from, $to, ($subject || ()), '',
                          $content;

close(SENDMAIL);
```